# Newby Tutorial: React.js is not rendering Function Component

Tags: reactjs, components, render, react-dom

I'm trying out very basic tutorial, but cannot make the function component to render.  Would appreciate some help.

The following works fine:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';

const rightCol = <h1>This is the Right Column</h1>
const leftCol = <h1>This is the Left Column</h1>

const showInfo = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('showInfo'));
showInfo.render(leftCol);

const showBalls = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('showBalls'));
showBalls.render(rightCol);
```

But, if I try with a function, it doesn't work:

```
const leftCol = () => {
  return (<h1>This is the Left Column</h1>);
}
    
const showInfo = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('showInfo'));
showInfo.render(leftCol);
```

or

```
function leftCol() {
  return (<h1>This is the Left Column</h1>);
}
    
const showInfo = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('showInfo'));
showInfo.render(<leftCol />);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must start this name of the functional component is uppercase!!!

Try `LeftCol` will work well.

[image]

Comment: This worked.  All the tutorials I've googled didn't mention that function had to be in uppercase for 1st letter.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because **leftCol** is a function so you must call it with parentheses. Try this:

```
showInfo.render(leftCol());
```

Comment: This worked.  All the tutors I googled didn't have parentheses.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Name of the component should be uppercase

```
const LeftCol = () => {
  return (<h1>This is the Left Column</h1>);
}
```